# How to Retrive proper data on Spinner from SimpleCursorAdpter in Android

Tags: android

hay i used the SimpleCursorAdapter from implement the data on the spinner.its going well. also to get data i used following code:

```
Cursor cursor = (Cursor) (spncomapnayname.getSelectedItem()); 
if (cursor != null) { 
    companyselected = cc.getString(cc.getColumnIndex(db.COMPANY_NAME)); 
}
```

it is working well.but it is for the getting data from the spinner.but now i want to set particular data on spinner which was inserted by the user for update for normal ArrayAdapter spinner we used:

```
spinnername.setSelection(adapter1.getPosition(abc));
```

so i want to know how to set data from the database on spinner.

here is my code:

```
cursor = db.getProductName(); 
adapter1 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor, new String[] { DB_Database.PRODUCT_NAME }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
spnproduct.setAdapter(adapter1);


purchaseproduct = purchasebundle.getString("clickedpurchaseproductname");
if(!purchaseproduct.equals("null")|| !purchaseproduct.equals("")) {
    System.out.println("purchaseproduct" + purchaseproduct); 
    String mypurchaseproduct=purchaseproduct;
    ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) spnproduct.getAdapter(); 
    int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(mypurchaseproduct); // set the default according to value 
    spnproduct.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
}
```

here i get data from bundle.i want to retrive data on Spinner.the data is populated from SimpleCursorAdapter

Answer (score 0):

First Get Selected Value From Cursor and store into `mString` Variable and then use below code for display this selected value into Spinner.

```
if (!mString.equals("null") || !mString.equals("")) {
    String myString = mString; // the value you want the position for
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdap = (ArrayAdapter<String>) mSpn1.getAdapter(); // cast to an ArrayAdapter
    int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(myString);
    // set the default according to value
    mSpn1.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
}
```

Comment: hay i used that code but it was shown me a error java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter. my spinner had populated data with SimpleCursorAdapter and used the ArrayAdapter may be because of that is throws a error.

Comment: purchaseproduct=purchasebundle.getString("clickedpurchaseproductname");    if(!purchaseproduct.equals("null")|| !purchaseproduct.equals(""))
  {
   System.out.println("purchaseproduct" + purchaseproduct);
   String mypurchaseproduct=purchaseproduct;
   ArrayAdapter<String> myAdap = (ArrayAdapter<String>) spnproduct.getAdapter();
   int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(mypurchaseproduct);
      // set the default according to value
   spnproduct.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
   
  }

Comment: @Kirti Post your full code into your question so it's easy to understand.

Comment: @Kirti sorry for that but i don't know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("columm_name"));
```

or to get a String

```
String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("columm_name"));
```